# How does spring-kafka listener retry work with max.poll.records greater than 1?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72304858/785523) and it is clear to me that records are handed to the listener one at a time before the next poll.

Can someone let me know if during the processing of any records, if the listener throws an exception will the entire batch be retried by spring-kafka or only the failing records will be retried by the listener with `DefaultErrorHandler` and `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`?

- spring-boot 3.0.12
- kafka client 3.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `DefaultErrorHandler` Javadocs:

```
 * An error handler that, for record listeners, seeks to the current offset for each topic
 * in the remaining records. Used to rewind partitions after a message failure so that it
 * can be replayed.
```

So, its behavior depends on a listener mode. In two words for record mode: only that failed records is retried. Even if your `max.poll.records > 1` in a record mode, only one record is fed to the listener. Others are just waiting in a line in memory until `DefaultErrorHandler` is done with the current record.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/annotation-error-handling.html